# SQL Server where clause not working on nvarchar column after database recovery

Tags: sql-server-2008, where-clause, nvarchar

We did database recovery task, recovery is done, but where clause is not working on `NVARCHAR` datatype column.

For example :

```
select * 
from table1 
where Job_Number = 'qba123456'
```

Comment: Please define `not working`, explain what happens. Also are the results different when you use the correct type? `select * from table1 where Job_Number = N'qba123456'` (notice the `N`).

Comment: 'not working' means after firing query select * from table1 where Job_Number = 'qba123456'. This query return 0 rows. I tried adding 'N' (select * from table1 where Job_Number = N'qba123456') but that also result 0 rows

Comment: If `select * from table1 where Job_Number = N'qba123456'` returns 0 rows than there is not a record in `table1` with a value in column Job_Number of `qba123456`. Maybe the record was not committed or maybe there are leading on trailing characters but the short of it is that value cannot be found.

Comment: There is no trailing characters before or after the value(job_number), when I search on the basis of ID(column primary key int) it works fine, but when I search any column that has nvarchar datatype, search does not work

Comment: If every thing is fine and still not working then there may be blank space, Have tried `TRIM` function `where TRIM(Job_Number)='XXXXX'`??

Comment: Database recovery task was done on 14 may 2016, after that this problem arised, but when I search for record which is before 14 may 2016 having jobnumber in the where clause that was generated before 14 may 2016, then it results 1 row, as expected, tried using this also select * from table1 where LTRIM(Rtrim(Job_Number)) = 'qba123456', but then also it return 0 row

Comment: What about the collation. Having a case sensitive collation on your database or nvarchar column could also affect the query.